# how to click on a image href and go to a new page. and display information from a phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, image, phpmyadmin, href

I am trying to use a image from a folder; click on it and make it select an id from the image to display information from phpmyadmin.

This is my php where I call for the info:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
include "dbcon.php";

$id = $_POST['val'];
try {
    $sql = "select name,discription FROM upcoming_events where id = '$id'";//if i put 1 or 2 for the $id it works
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo 'Error fetching scores: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    
        $row = $result -> fetch();
    $name = $row[0];
    $discription = $row[1];
    
    $gildiUt = "Nafnið er $name<br> lýsing er $discription";

?>

<?php 
include "../php/upcoming.php";
echo $gildiUt;
 ?>
```

This is the error I get when I try to run it. It  does not show $name of $discription but it does if I but in 1 or 2 for `$id`.

> Notice: Undefined index: val in
>
> E:\utsdata\hopar\GRU_H4\php\upcoming.php on line 5 Nafnið er lýsing er
>
> Nafnið er lýsing er

This is my html where the images is and the value is used to find the id
but it does not find the id. I am not sure if my value works for a image.

```html
     <form action="upcoming.php" method="post">
         <input type"image" name"val" value="1"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd1.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="2"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd2.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="3"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd3.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="4"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd4.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="5"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd5.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="6"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd6.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="7"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd7.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="8"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd8.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="9"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd9.png" alt="" width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="10"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd10.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="11"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd11.png" alt="" width="200" height="300"></a></li>
         <input type"image" name"val" value="12"> <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php"><img src="../myndir/upcoming/mynd12.png" alt=""width="200" height="300"></a></li>
      </form>
```

Comment: did you check echo var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: for undefined index error use isset($_POST['val']);

Comment: u have same name for all list like name ="val" try to give uniquely, that too having syntax error, not name"val" give as name = "val"

Comment: notice: your $id is weak to sql injection. You should prevent it.

Comment: No need for 'col-xs-12', since this is default in bootstrap. Also @daremachine is right. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3455727

Answer (score 1):

An `<a>` tag will make a `GET` request to the server.

Try having a link like this:

```
<a href="../upcoming/upcoming.html.php?val=1" />
```

and then accessing the variable using `$_GET[val]`

As the comments have suggested, you are not binding your parameters which makes your entire site vulnerable to SQL injection. Try taking a look [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: Please be careful. As @daremachine pointed out, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I have edited and added a link to PDO bound parameters